# C# list file in directory issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.0. I want to enumerate all files in a directory by creation time, i.e. files created more recently will be enumarate at first, older files will be enumerated at last. Any ideas how to implment this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that

```
System.IO.FileInfo[] array = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("directory_path").GetFiles();
Array.Sort(array, delegate(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
            {
                return f2.CreationTimeUtc.CompareTo(f1.CreationTimeUtc);
            });
```

Comment: Don't you have to revert the order to have more recent files first as asked ?

Comment: Second point : with VS2008, you can use lambdas, even in 2.0 or 3.0 ! Makes it easier to read... but you can use them only if your build process uses MsBuild 3.5 (mind the CI server for example...)

Comment: Oh, and the "var" keyword too ;o)

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use LINQ and a list... something like this should work:

```
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("YourPath");
 List<FileInfo> files = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime).ToList();

 foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I am using .Net 3.0, can not use LINQ. Any .Net 3.0 based solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try somithing like this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("path to folder");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
IOrderedEnumerable<FileInfo> enumerable = files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);

foreach (FileInfo info in enumerable)
{
  // do stuff...        
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am using .Net 3.0, can not use LINQ. Any .Net 3.0 based solution?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** updated, here's a non-LINQ solution

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo("directory").GetFiles();
Array.Sort(files, delegate(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2) {
    return f2.CreationTime.CompareTo(f1.CreationTime);
});
```

The above will sort by latest to oldest. To sort by oldest to latest change the delegate to: `return f1.CreationTime.CompareTo(f2.CreationTime);`

---

LINQ solution:

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo("directory").GetFiles();
var results = files.OrderByDescending(file => file.CreationTime);
```

Use OrderByDescending to sort by most recent CreationTime, otherwise use OrderBy to sort from oldest to newest CreationTime.

Comment: Added a non-LINQ solution based on your comment to another answer

Answer (score -1):

```
DirectoryInfo baseFolder=new DirectoryInfo("folderName");
FileInfo[] files=baseFolder.GetFiles("");
for(int i=1; i<=files.Length;i++)
for(int j=1; j<files.Length;j++)
{
    if(files[j].CreationTime > files[j+1].CreationTime)
    {
        FileInfo f = files[j];
        files[j] = files[j+1];
        files[j+1] = f;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of rewriting everything as the framework has a lot of stuff to order collections !